clean flutter BloC structure with background audio player
I am new to flutter and app programming and currently diving into Bloc concepts.
My project is an audio player with background playback ability.
I use just_audio, audio_service and flutter_bloc
It is clear that for small projects the whole thing could be done without all the stuff but I want to understand the architecture with audio_service and bloc and playing in the background.
I instantiate an
   audio_bloc
     which instantiates       my_audio_repository
        which instantiates    audio_service
           which has handler  just_audio

I understand communication should be like
if Widget Play Pressed 
    ->  add event to bloc
       -> bloc calls audio_repository.play
           -> bloc emits state audio_playing_state
               ->  BlocBuilder changes button based on audio_playing state

.... and so on with other buttons.
All communication flow diagramms always show that simple relation:
button -> event-repository action -> emit state -> change UI

like this picture:

so far so good ... here comes my problem concerning architecture:
Question 1: How to connect UI to progress Stream via bloc?
what if after "play" I want to display a progress bar continously.
That means listen to the progres stream.
In this case I would have the respository create an event on the bloc?? That means subscribing a "bloc.add(event)" callback as listener to the progress stream??
_audioPlayerRepository.positionStream.listen((progress) {
      add(AudioPlayerProgressEvent(progress:progress));
});

It works in my case, but I have never seen that structure detail in a bloc tutorial.
Is it a stupid idea to consequently route the progress stream via the bloc event/state?? Just for the sake of a clean bloc between UI and repository?
Question 2: How to get actual state of the player after playing in background.
As long as player widgets stays in foreground, I can listen to continuous stream of player state and update e.g. play/pause button.
BUT: what if the user changes to another screen and comes back -> player widget has to be build based on actual state of the player but without an event/state emitted.
How to transfer the player_status from player to UI in a clean architecture??
I could save a "player status" property in the audio_bloc
    -> add an event like aksForAudioPlayerStateEvent
      -> bloc emits State with player_status
        -> UI gets a State change and can update buttons.
   or
    -> call a auido_bloc -> getter on player_status directly (which would break the strict event/state mechanism.

Any hint is appreciated concerning if it makes sense to follow a strict structure.
